# "File ended whilst scanning use of \frac" - How to find the error?

Tags: sharelatex

I am using share latex and the way share latex works is that it ignores errors until there are to many in which case it will not compile.

All the errors come accompanied with the line on which the error is.

However the error ""File ended whilst scanning use of \frac" does not say the line in which the error is.

Previous experience tells me that this error means a fraction has not been inputted properly or I am missing a curly bracket but in my document I have many fractions and so what is the quickest way to find what line the error is in?

Comment: Normally the log shows the argument of the frac. Beside this you can move \end{document} up to find the location of the error. And don't ignore errors,  always correct them immediatly.

Comment: Just to expand on Ulrike's comment: if you really have no idea where the error is then start with the \end{document} at the halfway spot.  If no error, move it to the 3/4-way spot, but if there is an error in the first half then move the \end{document} to the 1/4-way spot.  You will find the error *very* fast this way.

Comment: As far as i know, ShareLaTeX doesn't ignore any errors. That would be a really really horrible thing for the users.

Comment: Note that it has to happen in your last paragraph since LaTeX would have issued another error (`! Paragraph ended before \frac was complete.`) had it encountered a `\par` (or double line feed) before the 'missing) closing brace.